# Is every weak $\infty$-bicategory (à la Lurie) an $\infty$-bicategory?

Tags: higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

In Definition 4.1.1 of [$(\infty,2)$-Categories and the Goodwillie Calculus I](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/GoodwillieI.pdf), Lurie defines a *weak $\infty$-bicategory* to be a scaled simplicial set that has the extension property with respect to every scaled anodyne morphism. In Theorem 4.2.7, he defines a model structure on $\operatorname{Set}_{\Delta}^{\operatorname{sc}}$, the category of scaled simplical sets, and in Definition 4.2.8 he defines an *$\infty$-bicategory* to be a scaled simplicial set that is a fibrant object in the model category $\operatorname{Set}_{\Delta}^{\operatorname{sc}}$.

Every $\infty$-bicategory is a weak $\infty$-bicategory, because every scaled anodyne morphism is a bicategorical equivalence (Proposition 3.1.13). What about the converse? Is every weak $\infty$-bicategory an $\infty$-bicategory?

EDIT:

I think I now have a proof that, indeed, every weak $\infty$-bicategory is an $\infty$-bicategory. I will post it tomorrow.

Comment: The property that the "anodyne" morphisms detect fibrancy of objects is a general feature of well-behaved model categories -- cf. [Olschok's theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.1627) generalizing Cisinski, or Simpson's "pseudo-generating sets". Anyway, Verity's model structure on 2-trivial stratified simplicial sets has this property and Lurie's model is a variation of Verity's model (although Verity's model lacks an appropriate "Rezk completeness condition", this can easily be added). I would be surprised if Lurie's model does not have this property, even if Lurie's techniques don't show it.

Comment: Actually, it's possible the the precise class of morphisms that Lurie chooses to call "anodyne" don't quite do the trick, but some slight variant of them at least should work.

Comment: A side note: I bigly disliked the morphism of Definition 3.1.3.(B) ( - which, by the way, contains a typo: the first instance of $\Delta^{\{1,3,4\}}$ should be replaced by $\Delta^{\{0,1,4\}}$ - ), but was very happy to find out that we may replace it (without changing the class of scaled anodyne morphisms) by the morphisms $f_1$ and $f_2$ of Remark 3.1.4.

Comment: Oh thanks for saying that! When I realized there was a typo there it ended up derailing my reading of the paper. Maybe I'll give it another go now! That morphism corresponds to the Rezk completeness condition, and in Verity's model it can naturally be handled using an injective map and just adding thinness to 1-cells. Verity's model just seems generally more natural to me.

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, Verity's model is fascinating. Although I must say that "natural" isn't necessarily the first word that comes to my mind when I think of complicial thinness extensions and complicial horn extensions… but perhaps that is only because of my yet very limited understanding of the matter.

Comment: I'm sorry, my remark above that we may replace the morphism in Definition 3.1.3.(B) by the morphisms $f_1$ and $f_2$ of Remark 3.1.4 without changing the class of scaled anodyne morphisms is most probably false. I found a mistake in my calculations. So sad.

Comment: The thing to remember about Verity's model is that the complicial horn fillers are all obtained from those in dimension 1 and 2 (which encode transport along equivalences and composition of 1-cells respectively) by taking pushout-joins with cofibrations (specifically, inclusions $\partial \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$. Likewise, the complicial thinness extensions are all obtained from the one in dimension 2 (which encodes 2-out-of-3) by pushout-joins with cofibrations. So the basic principle is just that everything is stable under join.

Comment: This is discussed in Observation 38 of [Weak Complicial Sets I](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604414) in the course of showing the related fact that Verity's anodyne extensions are closed under what I referred to as "pushout-joins", which he calls "corner-joins".

Comment: @TimCampion Wow. That fact should have been featured much (!) more prominently in Verity's paper, in my opinion. Now I completely agree that the class of elementary stratified anodyne morphisms is a perfectly natural class of morphisms to consider.

Comment: @TimCampion But not all complicial horn extensions can be obtained by pushout-joining some $\Lambda^k[n] \to \Delta^k[n]$ with $n \in \{1,2\}$ with some $\partial \Delta^m \to \Delta^m$, because no matter what we always have $0 \leq k \leq 2$, and the pushout-join is isomorphic to $\Lambda^k[n+m+1] \to \Delta^k[n+m+1]$. Perhaps a variation of that construction is needed?

Comment: You just have to pushout-join on both sides!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few years later, it has been shown by [Gagna, Harpaz, and Lanari](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.01905) that the answer is *yes*. Every weak $\infty$-bicategory is an $\infty$-bicategory.